# Get URL of the website that failed to load

Tags: javascript

At my school, many websites are blocked (not an unblocking question don't worry).

I am interested in building something that keeps a list of all blocked pages by me clicking a bookmark with Javascript code associated with it.

Problem is, there are two ways my school blocks things,

1. Is replacing the pages HTML with their own blocked message, meaning using Javascripts `location.href` works just fine.
2. Blocking the connection completely, giving me a `ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED` message. Because of this, `location.href` doesn't work (I suspect Chrome doesn't store that info). Is there anyway to retrieve the URL? It is still in the URL bar.

I haven't had many things to try as I am very new to Javascript.

Thanks in advance!

Here is my relevant code:

```
javascript:(window.open(location.href))
```

P.S. If this is a duplicate question or an easy one to solve, please let me know, I don't want to clog up StackOverflow with dumb questions.

Comment: Hello and Welcome to StackOverflow. This is a pretty good first question. People (myself included), will be more likely to be able to help you though if you provide some code. This actually piques my interest.

Comment: Ok Eli, here is my relevant code `javascript:(window.open(location.href))`. It doesn't do anything right now but open up the URL again, storing it to a file or variable is something I will look at later. I use Python quite often and I work by separating something I want to make into sections. Right now the first section is to figure out how to get the URL reliably. After that I will look at the rest, let me know if you need anything more. Thanks!

Comment: Well, maybe you could create another bookmark that does a `var url = prompt('url');` instead of trying to read from `window.location`. Then you could manually copy&paste the url...

Comment: So you want to build a html+ javascript web page, host/run it somewhere, and click on links on that page which go to other sites and want to mark the ones that don't work (for whatever reason)? Correct ?

Comment: BrunoLM, that does bring up a prompt, but it is empty unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a better way, depending on your specific needs.  Check into the new ServiceWorker.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API

Basically, you can intercept all the HTTP/HTTPS requests and handle them.  This also allows you to deal with data as it comes back.

This probably isn't a task for someone brand new to JavaScript, but worth looking at.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Brad! It would seem as though that is limited to Firefox, and I primarily use Chrome, thanks anyway!